# IF OR THEN in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did some Googling and made some progress, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I think it should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    IF(Substring(dbo.LIMIT_HIST.ID,8,5) = '.0010' OR
    Substring(dbo.LIMIT_HIST.ID,8,5) = '.0020' 
    Left(dbo_LIMIT_HIST.ID,18),"")) AS IDs
FROM
    dbo.LIMIT_HIST INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUSTOMER ON 
    dbo.LIMIT_HIST.LIABILITY_NUMBER = dbo.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE
```

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: syntax for doing what in sql?

Comment: hey why there is no "AND" or "OR" after '.0020' and Left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want a case statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN Substring(dbo.LIMIT_HIST.ID,8,5) = '.0010' 
            OR Substring(dbo.LIMIT_HIST.ID,8,5) = '.0020' 
       THEN Left(dbo_LIMIT_HIST.ID,18)
       ELSE '' 
    END AS IDs
FROM
    dbo.LIMIT_HIST INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUSTOMER ON 
    dbo.LIMIT_HIST.LIABILITY_NUMBER = dbo.CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_CODE
```

Comment: While Googling, I saw an example of Case...When, but I saw a lot more If...Then examples.  Very confusing.  It makes sense now though.

Comment: If then is usually used outside of the select to control logical flow of the code. [IIF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) was introduced in SQL 2012 and could replace the `CASE` statement in this case, since you only have a single `WHEN`. But, I'm glad you are all cleared up!